# How to shift the sum limits?

Tags: math-mode

I have a summation with long limits, I would like to specify the position at which I write the limits, is it possible?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}
\[\sum_\nolimits{t=i-r_{i}+d_j+1}^{r_i+d_i-1}f(t)\]
\end{document}
```

Using `\limits`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}
\[\sum\limits_{t=i-r_{i}+d_j+1}^{r_i+d_i-1}f(t)\]
\end{document}
```

but this is no looking good for me.

[image]

Can I specify the position at which I start the limits? Say for example, at the middle of the symbol sum I put the limits?

Something like this:
[image]

Comment: Side note, but I love your profile picture LOL

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With the `mathtools` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
\sum\limits_{\mathmakebox[1em][l]{t=i-r_{i}+d_j+1}}^{\mathmakebox[1em][l]{r_i+d_i-1}}f(t)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

(Change `1em` to change the position)